# Mapping the grid values to their physical ones

Tags: python, plot, axis-labels

I am doing a cosmological simulation. I have a contour plot which represents a density field. The y and x axes have values of grid points. I work with Python. What I want is, to put things in Mpc/h (distance unit). The size of my simulation box is 100 Mpc/h, so the range should be from 0 to 100. And I should modify both my x and y axes from grid points to Mpc/h.

I try to find a function to map my grid values (from 0 to 128) to my physical ones (0-100). Which is this function and how is it applied? Could someone help me with that please?[image]

Comment: Please provide some data to better help understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is my plot. In the x and y axes, there are grid points. I would like to modify both the axes labels into Mpc/h and a color bar to indicate the range of the values.